# Visual Studio Code Analysis shows Warning C6054

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

After running the code analysis on my solution I got, among others, a couple of *C6054 Zero termination missing* warnings.

Most of them I can comprehend and fix but the following example struggles me a bit.

```
char str[DEF_LEN+1];

if(condition)
{ 
    memset(str,'\0', DEF_LEN+1);

    while((strlen(str) + 1 + strlen(strToCat)) <= DEF_LEN)
    {
        strcat(str, "|");
        strcat(str, strToCat);
    }

    strncpy(otherString, str, DEF_LEN);
}
```

> Warning 6054: 'str' should be zero-terminated but may not be

Is it wrong that independent from the length of **strToCat**, the last byte of **str** is terminated anyway?

Is it caused by strcat or is the '\0' in memset not recognized as zero termination in this context?

The [MS help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C6054)&rd=true) for this warning tells me to set the first element in the string, but that is helpless obviously, isn't it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In your snippet, the `memset` is performed only if `condition` is true, so it *"may not be"*.

You could unconditionally initialize that variable at the declaration:

```
char str[DEF_LEN+1] = {'\0'};
```